# Why Signed and Released apk is not installing to the other devices?

Tags: android

Signed and released apk from `Android Studio` is not installing in other device and showing message `There was a problem parsing the package` when try to install. And lolipop devices are showing message `app not installed`. Only in USB debugging lolipop devices can play my app.

> compileSdkVersion 23
>   minSdkVersion 21
>   targetSdkVersion 23

Can anybody help me anyway?

Comment: Did you set security setting properly on those devices?

Comment: @hata in security setting -> device administrators -> unknown sources : is checked!

Comment: Do you already have the debug version installed? If so, uninstall and then try again with the signed apk.

Comment: @Henry i did it already :(

Comment: In that case, could you post the complete error that you get in logcat..

Comment: logcat has no error. :( i've to publish it to playstore today, but if i publish it, will it install to the other devices??? @Henry

Comment: Can't say anything for sure without figuring out why you are having this problem. If you are going to publish it and test it, Publish it as Alpha Test APK and check it out for yourself before going full on production.

Comment: :) i solved it. 

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
    }
}